# Where can I ask for programming advice?

Tags: discussion, computer-science

I don't want to spend my time asking a question just so that I can get it closed. I really need some advice but don't know where to ask it.

<sub>Question I have in mind is about choosing a programming language to learn given the conditions that I am in. Which I would explain. I am sure a question like this would get closed here at Programmers. But doing my own research on the manner has me spinning in circles and I feel I need some direction form an expert.</sub>

Comment: Is it a technical question? If so, stack-overflow is the place.

Comment: You can ask this question on meta.stackoverflow.com, there they can tell you the rules of each stack exchange site, however, you will need to give more details.

Comment: its about Chossing a programming language to learn given the conditions that I am in. Which I would explain. I am sure a question like this would get closed here. But doing my own research on the manner has me spinning in circles and I feel I need some direction form an expert.

Comment: @DEdesigns57: Unfortunately, you can't ask that here.  People are too afraid of "starting holy wars" to actually risk being helpful to new users honestly looking for information, and it would get closed in no time flat. :(

Comment: @DEdesigns57: StackExchange sites focus on questions that can be useful to others later on. Religious arguments aside, "chossing a programming language to learn given the conditions that I am in" sounds pretty specific to your particular case.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - it's not that people are afraid of starting holy wars, it's because ultimately "what language should I learn?" questions are either not constructive as everyone just chimes in with their favourite, or they're too localised because the OPs situation is so unique.

Comment: @DEdesigns57 the only good answer you will get is to try things out and  build yourself an opinion.

Comment: DEdesigns57 please don't do radical edits that completely change the question, as they render the existing answers useless. If you have a new question, well, just ask a new question, no point in editing an old one.

Comment: I'd advise you don't ask general programming questions on any SE site - it WILL be closed, and you WILL be ridiculed. Go to a more welcoming community like webmaster world.

Answer (score 7):

There are at least 6 Stack Exchange sites that address software development and programming topics.

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for programming questions, algorithm and data structure implementations, and software development tools.
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) for architecture, design, process and methodology, software project management, software licensing, and other "whiteboard" questions
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for best practices, security reviews, performance, correctness
- [Software Quality Assurance](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/) for quality control, automation, and testing
- [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) for different puzzles
- [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) for the mathematical and scientific foundations of computing

Comment: DBA for SQL and other databases, IT Security for writing secure code/other security matters, Sci Comp for doing Science! with programming, and UX for doing GUIs and the like. Also Game Design for well game design and programming.

Comment: ...and his question will be closed on all of them due to the content.

Answer (score 2):

A ***better phrasing*** of the question might be **"How do I choose a programming language to learn?"** and then **give your constraints**. I think this would be an appropriate question for programmers.stackexchange.com (and first check that someone else has not asked it - I would be surprised)

If you are wanting to learn a language just for **personal satisfaction** or to test the waters, any widely used general purpose language with nice friendly development environments will do. Don't pick really niche languages, as you generally won't have good documentation a broad community to help you.

If you are **thinking of a career change** you should research job adverts in your area or that you would be willing to relocate to, and see what languages they require - though typically they will want someone with a few years' development experience in the language, and that won't be easy to get unless you do some projects on your own or do some freelance work for people you know that will be patient while you learn.

If you are already an **experienced programmer** looking for the **right tool** for a very **specific job**, and you know for a fact your current language / platform will not be able to achieve the result you need, that would be an ideal question to ask this community in my view, but you need to spell out exactly why your existing language will not cut it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I Have changed my topic and edited my question. I have recently been banned from asking anymore questions on this site. It is my wish that I can regain that privilege. I have read the FAQ in better detail and now understand the nature of this site. I am sorry for the misleading topics that I have posted and hope to be able to post again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I can promise you that if you are confused about which language/technology to choose and the available information online about the language technology isn't enough for you to make a choice that you will only be **more confused** if you ask this question on Programmers and we do not close it.

You will have over 10 answers, filled with unverifiable claims, baseless opinions, jokes, arguments over pedantics, and comment discussions that have little to nothing to do with the answer or question.

This will more than likely mess you up more than if you just read a Wikipedia article about the two.  It will mess up other users too, nothing good is built of allowing it, nobody will ever benefit from it other than general amusement.  Then of course, the goal of this site isn't for the entertainment of the bored now is it?

This is what we mean by Not Constructive and we try to discourage such questions.

My best advice to you is to list out features that you want from a language/technology, then list pros and cons of each.  Look at the results and make an informed decision.  Recognize what is know as [Analysis Paralysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis) and also recognize it in yourself to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest asking in the programmers [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers) about help identifying some good languages to look into giving your situation. You may not get a response right away, but there's a fairly good chance someone will help you out with your question when they get a minute.

If you're still having trouble deciding after that, then sit down and figure out what you want to build, and narrow your language/technology choices down to 2 or so. Then create a question on Programmers telling us the specs of the project you want to build, and ask us if language A or B would be a better choice (and why) given the project and the situation.

It's important to include specific project specs, such as hardware requirements and estimated number of simultaneous users, and details about your situation, such as developer familiarity with the languages, how important deadlines are, etc. Keep in mind that the correct answer may be "both are equally valid, so pick whichever one you prefer"

Here's an [example of a question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/19893/1130) I asked a while back which was asking which language/technology was better for a specific project.

Comment: Asking in the chat room won't work for someone who has 1 reputation.